# Finding names of files or directories with certain name

Tags: linux, shell, find, glob

I have to find the name of files in the current directory that have at least 2 digits in them and end with a non-digit value.
So far I've done:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "[0-9]\{2,\}$[!0-9]"
```

But it isn't working. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Although in this case it is fairly obvious why it is not working, please avoid "it isn't working" and instead explain precisely how it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\{2,\}` is a regular expression thing<sup>1</sup>, while shells and find's `-name` option use shell patterns (a.k.a. globs). Use any of

```
ls *[0-9]*[0-9]*[!0-9]
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*[0-9]*[0-9]*[!0-9]'
```

`*` means any number of characters, `[0-9]` is a digit and `[!0-9]` is anything but a digit.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Also note that in regular expression, `[0-9]\{2,\}` would be "at least two consecutive digits". So it would not match `f1f2x` file. And the `$` would be totally out of place.</sub>

Comment: but doesn't this limit it to digits being only in between? what if my file starts with a digit? for example if I have a file name 2file44a will the glob expression you've provided work?

Comment: @kittycuddles Have you tried creating such a file and testing it? Yes, it will work, because `*` matches any string, including the null string. See `man glob`.